# How to use provided jmagick lib with Spring Boot executable?

Tags: spring-boot

My provided jmagick library located on /usr/share/java/jmagick-6.6.9.jar.

After start application I have error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: magick.MagickException

gradle.build has jmagick:

```
provided group: 'jmagick', name: 'jmagick', version: '6.6.9'
```

and application.properties has loader.path:

```
loader.path=jmagick-6.6.9.jar!/usr/share/java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Set 'ZIP' layout on build.gradle:

```
springBoot {
    executable = true
    layout = 'ZIP'
}
```

Create loader.properties:

```
loader.path=/usr/share/java/jmagick-6.6.9.jar
```